# How to convert from Hashbytes function's SHA2_256 encryption datatype to varchar(256) in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to implement a password encryption system using SQL in SQL Server 2012.

The `HASHBYTES` method must have only `nvarchar`, `varbinary` datatype.

```
update members 
set passwd = cast(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'asd123123') as varchar(256)),
    pwchangedat = GETDATE()
where userid = 'abcd1234'
```

The unexpected result of the `Select` query applied above update query:

```
?lZX?갅4磎?닽뙷?I?#?뚭?
```

I want to fix this `varchar(256)` data type string 'asd123123' applied SHA-256 encryption.

I want:

```
c82a6c7f5a58a915814334cda5a2ef88ab8cba922f49ec1623e2248ceabf7ddc
```

How can I get a solution?

Regards,

Comment: SO does not write code on demand, it helps you with your code, after you have written it and spent some time debugging it. Then provide a [mcve].

Comment: thank you, but i enough to solve thanks to scsimon's answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for...

```
select convert(varchar(256),HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','asd123123'),2)
```

See the [Binary Styles Section](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx) (since Hashbytes returns varbinary)

Thus....

```
update members set
    passwd = convert(varchar(256),HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','asd123123'),2),
    pwchangedat = GETDATE()
    where userid = 'abcd1234'
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback, but I want to apply to update query immediately. not the select query.

Comment: Um... ok... copy and past that where your have `cast(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','asd123123')as varchar(256)),`. I edited the answer

Comment: you should be using a salt with a hash for passwords... just a heads up. This prevents any two users from having the same hash.

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype is Varchar then we get the Same Hash code for literal string as well as the SQL Variable where as if the SQL Variable is of NVARCHAR datatype then you get different hash values when you use Literal String and NVARCHAR Variable using the SHA2_256 Function. Run the below code to check.

```sql
    DECLARE @VarcharInput  VARCHAR(70)  = 'Test';
    DECLARE @NVarcharInput NVARCHAR(70) = 'Test';

    SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','Test')         AS NewHashValue;
    --0x532EAABD9574880DBF76B9B8CC00832C20A6EC113D682299550D7A6E0F345E25
    SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',@VarcharInput)  AS NewHashValue; 
    --0x532EAABD9574880DBF76B9B8CC00832C20A6EC113D682299550D7A6E0F345E25
    SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',@NVarcharInput) AS NewHashValue;
    --0xE6FA3CA87B1B641AB646D3B4933BBA8D0970763F030B6578A60ABDEAE7366247
```